# Regex / BBCode Parser to find string between two strings (Between two strings) and replace it

Tags: php, regex

I couldn't come up with a better title, my apologies. Basically, we're going to have text that looks like this:

```
Wow, thanks for that image. It really helps!  
[quote]Here, this image may help you.  
[img]http://www.url.to.image.jpg[/img]  
[/quote]
```

The text could also appear as

```
Wow, thanks for that image. It really helps!  
[quote="username"]Here, this image may help you.  
[img]http://www.url.to.image.jpg[/img]  
[/quote]
```

So, what we're wanting to do is grab any images that are inside a quote and replace those `[img]` tags with `[url=http://www.url.to.image.jpg]Click here to view the image[/url]`.  But this operation should ONLY happen for images inside quote tags. I've looked at the various BBCode parsers for PHP but can't find anything that would be able to do this, and I'm unsure of the regex required for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(\[quote[^]]*].*?)(?=\[img])\[img](.*?)\[/img]
```

with replacement string

```
$1[url=$2]Click here to view the image[/url]
```

Not sure of the code.  Perhaps:

```
$result = preg_replace('%(\[quote[^]]*].*?)(?=\[img])\[img](.*?)\[/img]%sim', '$1[url=$2]Click here to view the image[/url]', $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

We must ensure that there is no `[/quote]` before `[img]`. This can be done by not using `.*?`, but `((?!\[/quote]).)*`

```
$regex = '#(\[quote[^]]*]((?!\[/quote]).)*)\[img](.*?)\[/img]#s';
$replace = '$1[url=$3]Click here to view the image[/url]';
$str = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
```